# The difference between Hollow and Copse

Tags: meaning, differences

What is the difference between a hollow and copse in the sense of a hollow as a feature of woodland? Wikipedia gives this definition:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hollow

'*Hollow, a low, wooded area, such as a copse*'

Comment: And… where’s your research of copse?   Also try googling “copse on a hill”

Comment: See https://www.ahdictionary.com/word/search.html?q=hollow also.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***Hollow***

I felt so certain that *hollow* had a specific sense, related to woodland, that following @Xanne's link, I looked it up in the OED.

However the esteemed work had nothing of that kind, beyond its sense 2.

*spec. A depression on the earth's surface; a place or tract below the general level or surrounded by heights; a valley, a basin.*

And none of the examples it gives - between 1553 and 1885 - reference trees or woodland.

Nonetheless I feel sure that I, like I sense you have too, have seen it used in reference to a clearing in a wood or forest. That probably counts as an example of its sense 1 meaning, of:

*A hollow or concave formation or place, which has been dug out, or has the form of having so been:  †(a) a hole, cave, den, burrow (obsolete);  †(b) a hole running through the length or thickness of anything; a bore (obsolete);  (c) a surface concavity, more or less deep, an excavation, a depression on any surface;  (d) an internal cavity (with or without an orifice); a void space;*

***Copse***

A *copse* - a syncopation of ***coppice*** - is simply:

*A small wood or thicket consisting of underwood and small trees grown for the purpose of periodical cutting.*

Its etymology is *Old French* (originally Latin *colpaticium* - 'having the quality of being cut').

Quotations from OED - online edition.

Comment: I see that the drive-by shooter has been out and about again. Please have the courtesy to state why you have downvoted something!

Comment: The AHD calls it “a small valley between hills or mountains,” certainly distinct from a copse. Americans living in the Appalachian region pronounce it “holler.” Popularized by J.D. Vance’s 2016 best seller *Hillbilly Elegy.* Upvoted.

Comment: I didn't downvote, but *hollow* has a different meaning in Appalachia. [Hollow](http://artsandsciences.sc.edu/appalachianenglish/node/492#:~:text=hollow%20noun%20A%20small%2C%20sheltered,especially%20Southern%20Appalachians%2C%20Ozarks%E2%80%9D%5D):  *A small, sheltered valley that usually but not necessarily has a watercourse. The term occurs often in place names, especially informal ones, as Hell’s Holler (NC) and Piedy Holler (TN).* This is probably the meaning the OP (and you) remember. Most of Appalachia is woodland, so most hollows there will be, as well.

Comment: @PeterShor I once spent a day in the 'Blue-Ridge mountains of Virginia' when staying with friends in Washington. I don't remember any *hollers* but it was certainly lovely country.  Quite what I've read that makes me associate it with woodland, I'm not sure - perhaps Mark Twain.